# How can I add an Ubuntu 16.04 desktop to a Windows active directory which is XXXX.local?

Tags: 16.04, active-directory, likewise

I am trying to add my Ubuntu 16.04 machine to a Windows 2012 R2 active domain. I keep getting the message that it cannot join. I had the same problem trying to do the same thing with an Apple Mac and it seems to have something to do with the domain name which is XXX.local. Some research seems to show that a program likewise-open-gui can help in this situation but this is now no longer available for 16.04. I have installed Kerberos, Samba and Realmd but no luck so far following the instructions. Is there anyone out there who has done this successfully for a XXX.local domain? I have a whole classroom full of Ubuntu PCs to join to the  school domain! I wish they hadn't just come in and set up a .local domain on my day off!

Comment: The .local domain is... not something AD can index, nor is it something that actually is *used* outside of the local computer's 'domain' or workgroup typically.  Also, `.local` has some special connotations regarding its usage, and typically is NOT used for an AD zone.  You'll have to have the IT team come up and set up the AD zone to be a bogus domain but still something that is a domain (and not .local), and then try and join those systems to the domain.  `.local` is not really a 'usable' AD domain in the long term with Linux.  (That part is offtopic here though)

Comment: But extremely useful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used PBIS:

https://github.com/BeyondTrust/pbis-open

I needed to install SSH, remove avahi-daemon and then follow the PBIS installation instructions.

It has successfully joined the domain even though it is a .local one.

I am now working on getting the domain user login to work!

Comment: Login works as long as I use username@XXXX.local at the login screen.